# Is it possible to stop a dynamically inserted script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it somehow possible to stop a script tag from loading after is has been added to the head of a HTML document?

I would like to have something like this:

```
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script_tag.setAttribute('src', 'http://fail.org/nonexistant.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_tag);

// something like this!!!
script_tag.abort();
```

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Did you try `head.removeChild(script_tag);`? I'm not sure if it would work though.

Comment: @Rory Fitzpatrick: From the looks of it he wants to abort downloading a script if it's taking too long to fetch from an external source.

Comment: @Rory Fitzpatrick: I'm a javascript framework developer and we do have a wrapper for those kinds of script loading. If someone disposes the wrapper object, i need to cancel the request. Currently, we just remove the listeners to get it working but it's not really what I think of when I dispose something.
@Amarghosh: Thanks for the hint but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible in any cross-browser manner.  As soon as the script tag is added to the head it will be downloaded and parsed and even removing the node won't stop it.

That being said, Firefox has [`document.onbeforescriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onbeforescriptexecute), which is cancellable (where the default action would be to execute the target script).  This event was originally on a standards track but was recently removed from the HTML spec due to a lack of valid use cases.

Comment: "lack of valid use cases" - meanwhile I need this. The person who asked probably needs this. Just ugh.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do this this way. But you can if you load it via XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX). This way you can abort connection if it takes too long.
For example you can use `timeout` option if you use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ url: "a.js", dataType: "script", timeout: 1000});
```

This way if script doesn't load within 1 sec (1000ms) request will be aborted. Also you can use `{async:false}` to prevent code execution while script is loading (if you need to).

Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that does not always work due to cross domain restrictions.

Comment: What about `jsonp`? This way you can do crossdomain. But be sure you trust that domain.

Comment: JSONP is just dynamic `<script>` tag injection, so the same problem with not being able to abort an existing request is there.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer do allow you to cancel scripts loading:

- remove the script from the page e.g. `<script id=blah src=...></script>` and `blah.parentNode.removeChild(blah);`
- then do a garbage collection `window.CollectGarbage && CollectGarbage();` (not always necessary since large page will cause a GC to happen anyway)
- don't try testing using the debugger (it interferes, e.g. GC)
- you need a `<script async` (or defer?) property, otherwise later scripts won't execute on the page (note your scripts must correctly handle out-of-order script loading due to the `async` property).
- IE/Edge only act as if the script loaded, but they don't actually close the connection (not sure what it does if the script eventually does load).
- this technique stops the throbber, makes the pageload event fire (**very** important for jQuery),  and resize events fire (otherwise they don't while page is "loading").
- the technique doesn't work for Chrome or Firefox
- an XMLHttpRequest (CORS if necessary) is likely a far better implementation since you can control the timeout and abort()
- I only tested Internet Explorer 11 and Edge 13