# Convert script load promise to Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have this script load promise which I need to convert to an observable. I need to cancel this promise on ngOnDestroy which after googling I found that is not possible, hence I want to convert this to an observable.

```
this.visualizePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    script.setAttribute('src', `${process.env.JASPER_SERVER}/client/visualize.js`);
    script.onload = () => {
        console.log('script loaded')
        window['visualize']({
            auth: {
                name: process.env.JASPER_NAME,
                password: process.env.JASPER_PASSWORD,
                organization: process.env.JASPER_ORGANIZATION
            }
        }, resolve, reject);
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
        this.errMsg = true;
        this.error = 'Failed to load visualize';
        this.showLoader = false;
    };
    document
        .body
        .appendChild(script);
});

this
    .visualizePromise
    .then(visualize => {
        if (typeof visualize.report === 'function') {
            return visualize;
        }
        throw 'Failed to load visualize';
    })
    .then(visualize => {
        this.visualize = visualize;
        this.showLoader = false;
        // do stuff here
    })
    .catch(() => {
        this.errMsg = true;
        this.error = 'Failed to load visualize';
        this.showLoader = false;
    });
```

I want to change it to something like this,

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"

// create observable
const simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {

    // observable execution
    observer.next("bla bla bla")
    observer.complete()
})

// subscribe to the observable
simpleObservable.subscribe()

// dispose the observable
simpleObservable.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: are you trying an async service call

Comment: `Observable.fromPromise`

Comment: Edited Question- I need to cancel this promise on ngOnDestroy which after googling I found that is not possible, hence I want to convert this to an observable.

Comment: @IngoBürk this will change nothing because cancelling this observable will not cancel what's inside the promise

Comment: It's not possible to abort loading a script, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100784/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-dynamically-inserted-script-tag

Comment: I dont want to abort loading of the script, but what I want to do is cancel the execution of the then method of the promise I created.

Comment: @RemyaJ If my answer solves the question, please mark it as accepted. If not, please explain why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarifications in the comments, you can do the following. I kept all of your logic, including the (questionable) decision that `script.onerror` didn't reject (nor resolve) the promise. Thus, if the script fails to load, this observable will never complete.

```
const visualize$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  const resolve = val => {
    observer.next(val);
    observer.complete();
  };

  script.setAttribute('src', `${process.env.JASPER_SERVER}/client/visualize.js`);

  script.onload = () => window['visualize']({
    auth: {
      name: process.env.JASPER_NAME,
      password: process.env.JASPER_PASSWORD,
      organization: process.env.JASPER_ORGANIZATION
    }
  }, resolve, observer.error);

  script.onerror = () => {
    this.errMsg = true;
    this.error = 'Failed to load visualize';
    this.showLoader = false;
  };

  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

---

Side note, you mentioned

```
// dispose the observable
simpleObservable.unsubscribe()
```

which will never work because unsubscribing happens on a subscription, not on an observable.

Answer (score 0):

I made a live example, just check it out, [convert-script-load-promise-to-observable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/convert-script-load-promise-to-observable?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts). Just keep it mind that if you want to add auth header to some request you should do it in an [Interceptor](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).

**your.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
      let script, process;
      this.mySubcription = this.service.fromPromiseToObservable(script, process)
          .do(visualize => {
              this.visualize = visualize;
              this.showLoader = false;
              // do stuff here
          }).subscribe(visualize => {
              if (typeof visualize.report === 'function') {
                  return visualize;
              }
            return Observable.throw('Failed to load visualize');
    }, () => {
        this.service.errMsg = true;
        this.service.error = 'Failed to load visualize';
        this.service.showLoader = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.mySubcription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**your.service.ts**

```
fromPromiseToObservable(script, process): Observable<any> {
      this.visualizePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      script.setAttribute('src', `${process.env.JASPER_SERVER}/client/visualize.js`);
      script.onload = () => {
          console.log('script loaded')
          window['visualize']({
              auth: {
                  name: process.env.JASPER_NAME,
                  password: process.env.JASPER_PASSWORD,
                  organization: process.env.JASPER_ORGANIZATION
              }
          }, resolve, reject);
      };
      script.onerror = () => {
          this.errMsg = true;
          this.error = 'Failed to load visualize';
          this.showLoader = false;
      };
      document
          .body
          .appendChild(script);
    });

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.visualizePromise);
  }
```